# What is the process to create an even exchange?

Tags: orders

I'm new to Magento and I need some help.

I'm not sure how to create an even exchange without charging the customers credit card again.  Let's say the customer purchased item X in a small but wants a medium. Normally, I'd create a new order for the medium and charge the credit card.  Then, once we receive the small in the warehouse a credit would be issued to the card.

My problem is we do not save the credit card information in Magento. This requires us to contact the customer for their credit card number when we place the new order.  Is there an easier way to do this?

I have the same problem if we make a mistake in shipping.  The customer ordered a medium but we send a large.  I'll issues a call tag for the large and send out the correct product but again I need to get the customer credit card.

thanks

Comment: We would like the customer record to show that a a transaction took place.  A product was returned and a new product has been shipped.  You are correct, I could just do the switch but then there is no record of it in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

If the price of the order is the same, you can create a fake payment method available only in the backend, then edit the order (cancel and create a new one) and for payment method use the the fake one you just created.